# Regex xml date expression

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have a deserialized xml which looks like this:

http://wklej.org/id/2869540/

How to write a regex to find and return only first date expression `23.12.2010`, which may be another in every another xml documents.

I have never used regex and I don't even know how to write a pattern for it. Please help.

Comment: If the date always appear at `line=7` and `id=17`, you should go with XML parser.

Comment: If what you want is a regex to detect a date with a pattern of `dd.mm.yyyy`, then what you need looks either like `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` or like `\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d{4}` if you could have a date like `1/2/2010` instead of `01/02/2010`.

Comment: Its not, i have to do it by regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Regex for HTML/XML parsing. Use Html/Xml parser. Here is explain well why you should not use it.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg?rq=1)

You can load the string in XDocument or XmlDocument and using linq to take whatever you need.

Here little example of how to do it:

```
string str =
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<!-- comment at the root level -->
<Root>
    <Child>Content</Child>
</Root>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
```

After that select needed nodes using linq and take the value. Here this question could help:

[Finding element in XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460464/finding-element-in-xdocument)

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'll try that ;)

Comment: @GrzesiekZimnoch you can accept the answer if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the others, use a Html/Xml parser. If you really want to use regex, you can try this:

```
 string xml= "yourXMLString";
 string pattern = @"\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}"; //also matches dates like 1.3.2016. Use \d{2} to only match 01.03.2016
 Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

 Match m = regEx.Match(xml);   // m is the first match
 if (m.Success)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value); //prints the first found date
 }
```

Comment: ok. Thank you. I have that problem that my program need to read all docs looks like this one. One has date like 01.01.2000 , other has date like 01/01/2000, other 01- 01- 2000, and other 01 - 01 - 2000. Don't know how to solve it with pattern.